# Can a Catholic priest hearing a person's confession recall the content of earlier confessions?

Tags: catholicism, confession

In answer to my question on situations where a priest hearing the confession can deny absolution, a few answers say that denial can be done if the person confessing is not ready to refine his life. That condition is mostly borne out of linking of the present confession to the earlier ones made by the same person. For instance, suppose Mr.A who is in public service, has a habit of taking heavy bribe from his clients. He makes frequent confessions , in each of which the priest advises him to refrain from his habit, but keeps on repeating the sin. Now, suppose he makes a fresh confession on 30.4.2022 to the same priest who had been hearing his confession. Mr. A confesses only the incident involving bribe, which he   committed after the last confession. Now, can the priest recall, during the confession of 30th April, the earlier confessions of Mr.A and the advice that had been given thereon ? Would doing so amount breach of trust and the seal of confession ? My question therefore,  is: Can a Catholic priest recall during a confession the content of previous confessions of the same person ?

Comment: It seems to me that maybe this has been asked before?

Comment: This would go into a category of spiritual direction and taken out of confession. Or the priest can give harder penance each time the penitent comes back with the same or bigger sin.

Comment: My question is different from the earlier question of 23. Feb,2018  in that  the earlier question speaks of confession deemed incomplete for various reasons. I am speaking of earlier confessions which were complete and absolved, but to which the confessor is able to draw a link because of the repetition of the sin confessed.